# SSRS linking two matrix tables

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, scope

I am using SSRS 2008.
I have a report with 2 different matrix tables having two different datasets as their sources.
The data comes fine in both the tables individually.
BUT
My issue starts where I have to use data from one table to calculate percentage in the second table.
Here are the details:

Table 1:
Contains columns: Date, Referal_Status ('1' for each valid row), Department

Table 2:
Contains Columns: Date, Membership_Status ('1' for each valid row), Department

In table 1, I need to show referral counts (sum of valid Status) grouped by month in columns, and grouped by department in rows. Also an additional row and column for totals of the same.
This is implemented with no issues.

In table 2, I need to show membership counts (sum of valid Status) AND **referals to membership percentage** grouped by each month in columns, and grouped by department in rows. Also an additional row and column for totals of the same. The issue starts when I try to implement the percentage calculation.

Let's say I have the membership counts number for April 2014 in the membership table. How do I take the referrals count number for April 2014 from the referral table and compute the April 2014 percentage as referal_num/Membership_Num * 100

The issue that I face is the scopes of both the matrix tables being different.

Please help me attain the above in the SSRS matrix tables.

Am I providing enough information to get through to you folks about my issue? Please let me know in case you need more information from me.

Answer (score 0):

This is often a road to misery, but anyway ...

I would use the Lookup Function to retrieve the Referrals count.  You will need to concatenate your two key columns (Date and Department) into one expression.

This sounds great and often works well. However when it doesn't work on odd rows or combinations of data, you are flying blind trying to debug it.

Good luck!

PS: actually for a reliable solution that is easy to debug, I would go back and combine the data upstream so it can be presented to SSRS in one Dataset. I would probably use SSIS for this.

Comment: Thanks Mike,Could you please do me a big favor and explain how it would be accomplished once I have combined the data upstream. I would assume you're asking me to do a 'union all' of the both tables and probably add another column that differentiates between referrals and memberships. This would have one dataset for the report instead of two, and then add filters in the respective tables to filter out the irrelevent data. What next?

Comment: No I would try to join the two datasets to produce one row with both measures on it.  As the scopes are different this would require grouping both sources on Month and Department.

Comment: There could be x rows in referrals and y rows in memberships. I don't understand the basis of linking the two entities. All I would need finally is the counts grouped by department and month.

Comment: I think I kind of misrepresented the contents of my tables. Please see the edited question now. each row in each table would have a status as '1' and the count will be the sum of status. Hence, say 8 rows in referrals table will have 5 rows with date in April2014, and 24 rows in Membership table will have 15 rows with date in April2014. Sum(Status) will give the counts that I require. Which means for April2014 group, I need to calculate 5/15*100 %. I hope this is a little clearer.

Comment: As you said, all you need is the counts grouped by department and month. So for table 1 I would group by department and month and show sum (Referal_Status ).  Then I would "join" that with data from table 2, again grouped by department and month with sum ( Membership_Status ).  Final result is 4 columns: department, month, Referal_Status , Membership_Status, with one row per department + month combination.

Comment: I kind of got your drift... But by the time I got to read your reply, I had already implemented the pivot in the SP and used Lookup to fetch the data from the other dataset. But **Thanks for the help Mike** :)